# TextBox and button in panel control are not vissble in design ..?

Tags: asp.net, panel

i have taken one panel control in asp.net in that having one text box control and one button control ,when i open design the text box and button are not visible,when i run this i can see in the controls in browser

```
<asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server">
  <td align="center" colspan="4">
  <asp:Label ID="Label20" runat="server" Style="font-weight: 700" Text="search by phone number  : " ></asp:Label><asp:TextBox ID="txtphno" CssClass="ip" runat="server"  placeholder="Phone Number"></asp:TextBox>
  <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator2" runat="server" ForeColor="Red" ControlToValidate="txtphno" Font-Size="Large" ErrorMessage="*"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
  <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidator1" ControlToValidate="txtphno" ForeColor="Red" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Only Numbers" ValidationExpression="\d+"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
  <asp:Button ID="btnSearchphno" runat="server" CssClass="inputbtn" OnClick="btnSearchphno_Click" Style="font-weight: 700; height: 26px;" Text="search" />
  </td>
</asp:Panel
```

this is the source code what i have written please help me . .
thanks
teja

Comment: have you closed the </asp:Panel tag in the real life code or is that the issue?

Comment: dear Deniel, yea i have closed properly , , when i execute in browser its working properly

Answer (score 0):

Couple of points to get u started

1) Clear Your project solution and rebuild your project 
2) Restart your Visual studio instance and open your project freshly

Comment: Dear Manohar,i have done like that but same  problem i  am getting . .

Comment: close VS , go to task manager and delete the VS instance if it is exists , then reopen VS

Answer (score 0):

After you clear project and reopen visual studio, if problem still continue, try delete the designer and regenerate it.